# Finding the radio frequency of Wi-Fi-enabled electric motor

Tags: wifi-configuration, wireless-bridge

A friend of mine bought a Wi-Fi-enabled electric motor. He wants to control the motor with a remote control. However, he does not know what the radio frequency of the wireless transceiver.

How can we find the radio frequency of this transceiver?

Comment: WiFi mostly operates over the 2.4ghz and 5ghz spectrum depending on the WiFi standard it uses.  An RF receiver in the device for something as a remote control would be different and you would need to refer to the product documentation to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's truly a Wi-Fi device and not some simpler form of 2.4GHz radio, then you should find the model number, find a user manual for it online, and find out how to reset it to factory defaults and set it up again.

If he bought it used, it's probably searching for its previous owner's Wi-Fi network (SSID), and if that previous owner used wireless security such as WPA2, you won't be able to get in touch with it by setting up an wireless network with that same name, because it won't join it unless you know the right password. So the only way to get back in touch with that device wirelessly is to reset it to factory defaults and follow the usual procedure for setting it up from scratch.